# Dissmis NavigationViewController never dealloc the rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to show a modal view controller(view1) inside another viewController(view2)

### View1

```
@interface View1 : UIViewController
@property (weak) id delegate;

- (IBAction)closeButtonTapped:(id)sender ;
@end

@protocol View1Delegates <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)viewControllerDidFinish: (View1 *) viewController;

@end


@implementation View1

-(void)dealloc
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

}

- (IBAction)closeButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate viewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

@end
```

And I use the following code inside view2

```
@implementation View2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)onOpenView1Tapped:(id)sender
{
    View1 *view1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
    NavViewController *nav = [[NavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];
    view1.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:NULL];
}

- (void) viewControllerDidFinish: (View1 *) viewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

The problem is that the NavViewController calls its dealloc method but view1 never calls it at all after dismiss. This means that view1 will remains in memory .
How can I free the memory of view1 ?

Comment: What is that? '[[NavViewController alloc] view1];'?

Comment: And your nil-ing of the view controller needs to be in the completion if you're animating the view controller's dismissal... I'm not sure if that's your issue though since it seems to me that your current code should cause an error if it was actually doing as you'd intended.

Comment: I'm sorry @Avi Tsadok . I have modified my question.

Comment: You don't need to set the viewController to nil at all. Remove it and try again...

Comment: @AviTsadok I'm actually do not use it.I have just added it as a solution but it did not solve at all.So consider it not exist.The problem is still valid.

Comment: How are you calling `ViewControllerrDidFinish:`? Are you sure the `viewController` parameter contains the actual view controller?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have edited my question to clarify everything .

Comment: @SamehDos OK, a couple things. (1) Are you sure the spelling for your `ViewControllerrDidFinish:` method matches the delegate? And (2) in `ViewControllerrDidFinish` you're dismissing self (View2?), but nil-ing viewController (View1?)... What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to dismiss view2 or view1?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have edited the question again .I think now everything is clear.

Comment: @SamehDos It's not clear yet. Like I said What exactly are you trying to do in `viewControllerDidFinish:`? Are you trying to dismiss view2 or view1? Because you're dismissing "self" (i.e. view2), but you're passing in view1.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'm dismissing the navigationController that has View1 as its rootViewController.

View2 shows View1 and his navigation as presentViewController so View2 is the responsible for dismissing it . Clear?

Comment: @SamehDos But in your current code you're dismissing "self", i.e. view2. If you want to dismiss view1 you'll have to do `[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];` instead.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Nooooo I am not dismissing self . self here means that View2 will dismiss the presentViewController which is View1 and its navigation .Clear ?

Comment: @LyndseyScott By the way ,even I did as you told me ,the problem will happen again .The navigation is released but View1 is not.

Comment: @SamehDos Does View1 disappear as you expect though? (Releasing and disappearing are two separate things.)

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes,View1 disappears but it has not been released. It still lives at memory .I am gonna be crazy.

Comment: No need to go crazy. I'll just post an answer so you understand what I'm trying to tell you... One sec...

Comment: If you're using ARC the VC will get released by the system when it considers. If your VC doesn't have any retain loop, you're good to go. Dismissing a VC is something completely different than releasing one.

Comment: @codeFi but its navigationcontroller has been released so I expect that view1 will be released as well.

Comment: @SamehDos - you're right to expect that view1 will be released, but your question omits an important thing: what evidence do you have the it is not being released?  Are you implementing dealloc in view1 and setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: @danh Yes exactly I did that.

Comment: Please could anyone lead me to a good way how to implement what I want to do without memory leaks???